# Drawing two figures with directed lines specified by arrows

Tags: graphics, code-request, drawing

[image]

Can someone please help me to draw the attached figure in Mathematica?

Comment: Maybe the title should be modified to specify that the figures have arrows as this is the most difficult part I think (and the one that is maybe most useful to the community). Perhaps: " drawing two figures with directed lines specified by arrows" or "drawing two figures with arrows that flow along curves".

Answer (score 3):

Try e.g.:

```
cu1 = {Arrow[Line@Table[{x, 1/(x - 1) + 1}, {x, 1.1, 10, .1}]]} ;
cu2 = cu1 /. p : {_, _} -> ReflectionTransform[{1, 0}][p];
cu3 = cu1 /. p : {_, _} -> ReflectionTransform[{0, 1}][p];
cu4 = cu2 /. p : {_, _} -> ReflectionTransform[{0, 1}][p];
Graphics[{Arrowheads[{-.05, -.05}], cu1, cu2, cu3, cu4, 
  Arrowheads -> {-0.1, 0.1}, Thickness[0.01], 
  Arrow[{{0, 11}, {0, -11}}]}]
Graphics[{Arrowheads[{.05, .05}], cu1, cu2, cu3, cu4, 
  Arrowheads -> {0.1, -0.1}, Thickness[0.01], 
  Arrow[{{0, 10}, {0, -10}}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edits: Show[plot1,plot2]->Plot[{func1,func2}], Row->GraphicsRow

You might find better answers from people here that know how to use Graphics better than me but a semi-manual approach is possible with drawing tools in Mathematica.

Step 1:

```
Plot[{1/x,-1/x}, {x, -1, 1}, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Black]
```

Step 2:

Use line and arrows in drawing tools by right-clicking the plot and then clicking on drawing tools.

output:

[image: plot]

Step 3:

Do similar manipulations for the other plot

Step 4:

copy each plot (right click copy graphics), stack them side by side  and use :

```
GraphicsRow[{plot1,plot2}]
```

I personally used Inkscape when I wanted to modify plots.

Comment: Your first step can be simplified to `Plot[{1/x, -1/x}, {x, -1, 1}, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Black]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you.  I will edit the code